# Why are these decorators called from outermost to innermost, not the other way round?

Tags: python, tornado

I have the following method inside a `tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler` subclass:

```
@authenticate_user_async
@gen.coroutine
def on_message(self, data):
    """
    Callback when new message received via the socket.
    """
    # do stuff...
```

The `@authenticate_user_async` decorator is below:

```
def authenticate_user_async(f):
    """
    Authentication decorator based on http://tornadogists.org/5251927/

    Authenticates the user's credentials and sets self.current_user if valid
    """
    @functools.wraps(f)
    @gen.coroutine
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do stuff...

        f(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

I thought that the innermost decorator was called first, so would have expected to need them to be given:

```
@gen.coroutine
@authenticate_user_async
def on_message(self, data):
   ...
```

but only the first version works and the one above is never called if the `yield` keyword is inside the `on_message()` method.

Why is it necessary to use the first version and not the second?

Comment: I think this is a potentially interesting question. However, the complexity of its dependencies makes it impenetrable to anyone but the most determined reader. If it were rephrased in terms of an SSCCE (http://www.sscce.org/), this might make a bit more accessible and therefore useful to future readers (and would probably attract more answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I think I gave you this bug in my answer to your previous question, sorry.)

The line in `authenticate_user_async` where it calls `f` needs to be changed. Change this:

```
f(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

To this:

```
yield f(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now swap the order of decoration for `on_message`:

```
@authenticate_user_async
@gen.coroutine
def on_message(self, data):
```

In `authenticate_user_async`, "f" is your `on_message`. These two fixes ensure that "f" is a coroutine and that it gets run to completion.

Comment: Hmm, the `yield f` doesn't seem to be required as long as I make the `@gen.coroutine` the innermost decorator. But I think I understand now. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah; if `f` had a return value then you'd want to `yield f()` so you could wait for it to complete. In this particular case it's good style but not required.